# Does BuddyPress Have An Action Hook for remove_user?

Tags: buddypress, actions

BuddyPress has a behavior for removing users that does not run through WP's `deleted_user` action.

I have a hook in my plugin for `add_action('deleted_user', 'myScript');` but it only works for WP-related user deletes. It does not run when I remove a user in BuddyPress.

Has anyone hooked to the BP remove user action in their plugin?

If so, what is the action to catch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

buddypress users are actually wordpress users, there is no buddypress user separate from a wordpress user. But maybe `add_action('delete_user', 'myScript');` might be helpful which runs before the user is deleted. Buddypress itself uses this action, for example: `add_action( 'delete_user',       'bp_core_remove_data' );`